# Установка сертификатов через приложение в IIS. Проблема с правами

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, права, windows-server, сертификат

Опишу ситуацию:

- Windows Server 2016;
- Учетная запись с правами администратора;
- Под данной учеткой поднят веб-сервер IIS;
- На нем крутится приложение ASP.NET MVC;
- В приложении есть функционал, который должен ставить/удалять
  сертификаты, делает это либо кодом, либо командами в cmd,
  работает с локальным хранилищем;

При разработке на обычном компе запускал под админской учеткой из студии, работало все нормально.

После публикации на сервер не дает работать с локальным хранилищем сертификатов из приложения, ругается, что нет доступа. С файловой системой работает нормально. Установить просто руками могу.

Вот собственно вопрос, какие права и кому надо выдать на сервере? Я плохо разбираюсь в этом, поэтому буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: По всей видимости - без прав администратора тут особо никак.

Comment: Нашел ответ с решением проблемы:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18637426/8475399

Comment: Ну дык Local System обладает правами администратора же (на самом деле еще выше).

Comment: Вряд ли хорошей идеей является запускать произвольные веб-приложения  с такими правами.